# Under gdb-mi can I attach a command to a breakpoint?

Tags: gdb

I use gdb-mi in order to have access to gdb-many-windows functionality.

I would like to access gdb's ability to attach a list of [commands to execute once a breakpoint gets hit](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands).  Documentation suggests that the gdb/mi protocol supports this via the [-break-commands](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI-Breakpoint-Commands.html#GDB_002fMI-Breakpoint-Commands) verb.  That said, there is a cryptic suggestion of a [rough edge](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI-Compatibility-with-CLI.html#GDB_002fMI-Compatibility-with-CLI) earlier in that same documentation.

So am I just out of luck or is there some magic emacs or gud incantation that will grant me access to -break-commands functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Given the "[rough edge](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI-Compatibility-with-CLI.html#GDB_002fMI-Compatibility-with-CLI)" I referenced in my original question I decided to investigate prompt handling in gud.el.  Based on nothing more than a hunch I tried changing the two lines (~783 in function gud-gdb) from:

```
  (setq comint-prompt-regexp "^(.*gdb[+]?) *")
  (setq paragraph-start comint-prompt-regexp)
```

to

```
  (setq comint-prompt-regexp "^>|((.*gdb[+]?) *)")
  (setq paragraph-start "^(.*gdb[+]?) *")
```

This has the effect of preserving paragraph separation according to the original regex prompt pattern while allowing stripping of the single leading '>' prompt that gdb uses when collecting a commands list.

Amazingly it seems to work!  Though **info br** shows breakpoint associated commands lists the gdb-many-windows Breakpoints window gives no indication of their existence.  But that is a small nit.  For now I am happy.

Answer (score 1):

I also like to use commands attached to a breakpoint.  If I enter the
gdb command:  `comm 3`, it starts collecting the commands for the breakpoint, but when I enter `end` it does not recognize the command list has been completed and continues to prompt for more commands.  However, if I enter the full gdb command name, `commands 3`, then it does recognize that `end` command and the command attachments work.

Comment: Lovely! I wish I could upvote more than once, this has been bugging me of and on for years.